# Don't encode urls in querystring stringify

Tags: node.js, query-string

Is there any option for `qs.stringify` that will **not** encode the urls?

```
$ node
> var qs = require("querystring");
undefined
> qs.stringify({"url": "http://domain.com"});
'url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com'
```

I want the folowing output:

```
'url=http://domain.com'
```

Comment: This begs a good question: Why? That's not a valid query-string, which is why they're encoded.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I use youtube api and I got an error. I thought that the problem was the encoding of the url, but it wasn't... The problem was that I forgot `response_type` parameter. :-) Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, no.  Although, if you are not escaping the value in the query string then there is hardly any benefit to using querystring at all.  Mind as well just do: `var q = 'url=http://domain.com'`

EDIT: From looking at the source, the only way would be to change the behavior of (i.e. overwrite) the querystring escape() function - which is possible but not a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little late, but for the next person, you can do: 
    querystring.unescape(myString)

Comment: Just remember that this will also unescape everything else, so `%20` will be rendered into ` ` (a literal space) and so on...

Answer (score 6):

Late answer again, but...
`qs.stringify()` has option `encode:false` which actually disable the URI encoding.

[Qs.stringify documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/qs#stringifying)

You can also use it in nodejs `request/request` module as:

```
request({
  url: 'http://url.domain'
  qs: {
    qs1: 'thisIsNotEncodedInTheRequest%20://асд'
  },
  qsStringifyOptions: {
    // encoding: false /** (OLD VERSION - I think is deprecated yet) */
    encode: false
  }
});
```

Comment: It appears to have changed, or always was, to encode as opposed to encoding. So `encode: false`

Comment: https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
qs.stringify({url: "http://domain.com"}, { encodeURIComponent: uri => uri });
```

The option "**encodeURIComponent: uri => uri**" is to disable the encoding.

Comment: It still does not work with browserify https://github.com/mike-spainhower/querystring/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
qs.stringify({url: "http://example.com"}, null, null, { encodeURIComponent: qs.unescape });
```