# calling external rest api from node without encoding querystring params

Tags: node.js, rest, express, node-request

I am trying to call an external `rest API` from node server by using `request` node module.

```
let request = require('request');

var options = { 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://somerestURI:3000',
  qs: { msg: 'some|data|for|other|server' } 
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

If I try to run the above code, query string value is being encoded to

```
some%7cdata%7cfor%7cother%7cserver
```

as a result I am not receiving correct response.

But if I fire the same request in ***POSTMAN***. I am receiving the expected output(I think postman is not encoding query string).

So what I want is don't encode the query string value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387219/2100197), you can disable `encoding` in `qsStringifyOptions`

```
var options = { 
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://somerestURI:3000',
   qs: { msg: 'some|data|for|other|server' },
   qsStringifyOptions: {
      encoding: false
   } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...Added the edit you suggested but not working....when i dig into the request source code this is the line which is encoding query string value `var qs = self._qs.stringify(base)`, where it is not checking for qsStringifyOptions.

Comment: after adding `encoding: false` `url.parse` in `request` module is encoding the query string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) package. It allows connecting to any REST API and get results as javascript Object.

```
var HttpClient = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

// GET Call
httpClient.get("http://remote.site/rest/xml/method", function (data, response) {
       // parsed response body as js object 
       console.log(data);
       // raw response 
       console.log(response);
});)
```

or for POST Call

```
var args = {
     data: { test: "hello" },
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
};
//POST Call
httpClient.post("http://remote.site/rest/xml/method", args, function (data, response) {
      // parsed response body as js object 
      console.log(data);
      // raw response 
      console.log(response);
});
```